# Reverse order of elements in 2-dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Saw similiar (not the same, though) quesion yesterday and I realized I do not know it either.
Lets say there we have a 2 dimensional "`int[,]`" array  with elements like this:
1,2,3,4,5
5,4,3,2,1

And I want to reverse elements order in both <strike>dimensions</strike> rows:

5,4,3,2,1
1,2,3,4,5

Or just in one:

5,4,3,2,1
5,4,3,2,1

Only way I could think of is doing that manually in for statement. Any other idea?

Comment: *"Only way I could think of is doing that manually in for statement."* well, yeah.  What is wrong with that?  How else would you iterate through a 2d collection like that?

Comment: The first example shows a reverse in *one* dimension (though it is not clear if you meant in x or y dimension, since the array symmetric). The 2nd example shows a reverse of the first row which is an 1D array. So I think your question is completely unclear.

Comment: No, its not. Please red the description. The first shows reverse in both: first is now from 5 to 1, second now from 1 to 5. Both are reversed if you look at the original one. The second example shows reverse in the first dimension while the second stays the same. BUt it still 2 dim array.

Comment: dimensions is not the same as rows. In the first example, BOTH ROWS are changed, but only ONE dimension is reversed. If you reverse both dimensions of a symmetric array you would get the input back as result. Please update your question with a different example array, which is not symmetric.

Comment: due to you comments, I have edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Array.Reverse for each line of array.

**Update:**

If you can use array of arrays instead of two dimensional array:

```
var array = new int[2][];
array[0] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
array[1] = new int[]{5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  Array.Reverse(array[i]);
```

Comment: Rob, it was not there when I was typing my comment. But array of arrays is not 2-dim array (Matrix)

Comment: I think there is no another way. Or use array of arrays or implement loop manually.

Answer (score 0):

List have this operation built in.

List objects = new List();
objects.AddRange(arrayobjects);
objects.Reverse();