# How to put an array into another array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I have a chart that updates with the current bitcoin prices, however, the date and time on the x-axis is incorrect.  It always starts at Dec. 31, 19:00 hours.  In my console I am recieving the correct date and time, but I can't seem to get it to appear correctly on the chart.  I'm pretty sure I need to stick one array into another.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
          var result = JSON.parse(result);
          series = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            tempDate = Date.parse(result[i]['date']);
            tempArray = [parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];
            var date = new Date();
            tempDate = date.toString();
            series.push(tempArray);
            var tempDate = tempDate.concat(tempArray);
          }
```

Comment: Since when do numbers or strings have a `concat` method?

Comment: You add an array like you add any other value.

Comment: @Ian: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh jeez. Fail by me. Shouldn't have assumed. I can't believe I don't remember that...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, for every `i`:

- `result[i]['date']` gives the date at position `i`
- `result[i]['price']` gives the price at position `i`

Now first of all, let's take a look at your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

        //Here you grab the date from the result array
        tempDate = Date.parse(result[i]['date']);

        //Here you grab the price from the result array and parse it to a float
        tempArray = [parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];

        //Here you grab the current date (of today)
        var date = new Date();

        //Here you overwrite the 'grabbed date' with the current date (of today)
        tempDate = date.toString();

        //Here you add the price at position i to the 'result array' called series
        series.push(tempArray);

        //Here you join tempArray with the tempDate
        var tempDate = tempDate.concat(tempArray);
      }
```

So what exactly goes wrong?

Well I have prepared a JsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/KzLFr/1/

Look closely at the code and what exactly 'shows up' in the alert box. You see that the value of tempDate is overwritten by the current date. Applying this info to your loop: you will see that for each iteration, you overwrite the date that you grab from the `result` array with the current date.

This means that the 'actual' dates (from `result[i]['date']`) are always overwritten, hence, if you would add all the tempDates to an array at each iteration, you will end up with an array consisting of `result.length` times the current date.

Another interesting point is your statement: `var tempDate = tempDate.concat(tempArray);`
As you can see in the second alert box in the JsFiddle, this will create an array which has two arrays after each other. But why in the world would you do this in every iteration?

Also, you never **do** something with your dates. You don't add them to an array or anything: you just create them and then leave them alone.

This begs the question: what exactly do you want to do?

Therefore:

**NOTE:** It could be that I am mistaken, but if I'm right you want to end up with an array that contains the `x-axis` information and the `y-axis` information. Because it is **not** clear from your question and your code how you want to accomplish this, I can only guess.

So by guessing what you want to end up with, I would rewrite your loop as follows:

```
var dateData = [];
var priceData = [];

for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ){
  dateData.push( result[i][0] );
  priceData.push( result[i][1] );
}
```

You can see how this works here: http://jsfiddle.net/WT58s/1/

If that doesn't solve your problem, please explain with what you want to end up with (a two dimensional array or two different arrays?), so we can assist you better.

Also, often when you download information from the internet, the information is stored backwards; so starting with the current date and then going backwards in time.

Try and see if that is also the case with your data. If this is indeed the case, you can read about reversing here:

[Reverse order of elements in 2-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982860/reverse-order-of-elements-in-2-dimensional-array)

Comment: Thanks for explaining your answer in depth.  What I want to do is have the current time to appear on the x-axis of the chart.  When I console.log, the current time correctly shows up in my console.  But I cant get it to show on the chart correctly.

Comment: @evann: Can you give a link to the plugin you're using?